# CSS for Safari and Apple

Tags: ios, html, css, safari

I have a site I am building for a client and in need of a bit of help...Everything looks great in all browsers except for Safari and any Apply device.

If you take a look at the link below on Chrome or FF you will see the social icons on the top right look good, but when viewed on a Safari or Apple devices they stack on top of each other.

Would like to know what I could do to get this to be cross browser compatible....

http://msg.d1g.it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not quite sure why it doesnt work on safari, but why not apply `float:left` to the 4 `<a>` and give `header_html` a known width let it be `350px` so something like this:

```
.social_btns { /* give all your <a> this class */
   float:left;
}
.header_html {
   display:inline-block;
   float:right;
   line-height: 30px;
   padding-right: 10%;
   width:350px; /* add this line */
}
```

tested on safari 7.0.3 with web inspector